# Can't import the named export 'startOfWeek' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: reactjs

Why I am getting this I have install date-fns and I have trying to remove and update npm and node also remove package-lock json file but not resolved

import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

Thanks

I want to Date picker

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem. I resolved the issue by using an older version of react-datepicker.

When you run npm install react-datepicker it will install the latest version which is `6.1.0` and was published 5 days ago.

I picked a version from one year ago: 4.10.0

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker?activeTab=versions

Un-Install your current version and re-install naming a different version

```
npm uninstall react-datepicker 
npm install react-datepicker@4.10.0
```

then can apply the code

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

// CSS Modules, react-datepicker-cssmodules.css
// import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';

const Example = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)} />
  );
};
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker?activeTab=readme

Comment: Is there a bug ticket in the react-datepicker project for this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below versions of react-datepicker and date-fns to avoid issues.
`"date-fns": "^3.3.1", "react-datepicker": "^4.25.0"`